# Dynamically change target elements on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

In an attempt to make my function more dynamic, I want to change the elements it targets based on which parent div the user clicks.

So, this is to target the first portfolio section, but there will be three and I am trying to reuse the same function for each.

Here's what I started with-

HTML

```
<div class="portfolio-one">

    <h1 class="portfolio-one__overlay">heading</h1>

    <div class="portfolio-one__content">
    <button class="icon-times "></button>
    <h1 class="portfolio__heading">heading</h1>
    <p class="portfolio__description">Lorem</p>
 </div> 
</div>
```

jQuery

```
function showContent(){
    $('.portfolio-one').on('click', function(event) { 
        $('.portfolio-one__content').animate({
            left: "5", 
            height: "100%"
        }, 700, "linear");
        $('.portfolio-one__content').show();
        $('.portfolio-one__content button').show();
        $('.portfolio-one__overlay').hide();
    });
};
```

And what I would like to end with-

```
var target = ??;
var content = ??;
var button = ??;
var overlay = ??;

function showContent(){
    $('target').on('click', function() { 
        $('content').animate({
            left: "5", 
            height: "100%"
        }, 700, "linear");
        $('content').show();
        $('button').show();
        $('overlay').hide();
    });
};
```

I was going to use another function to populate the variables, but that seems the same as re-writing the function three times. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to achieve. It sounds like you're over complicating a relatively straightforward issue. Also, seeing your HTML may help.

Comment: Well, for one, you wouldn't do `$('target')`, you want `$(target)`.  You made `target` a variable, so you need to reference it as one, not a string.  Your `??` bits are going to be up to you, depending on what it is you want to do (we cannot tell)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am trying to populate the variables to animate, show, and hide based on which portfolio is clicked. So, if the first portfolio is clicked, the function targets it's classes. If the second is clicked, it does the same and so on.

Comment: You could achive this far easier in a single event handler using DOM traversal, but it would depend on how your HTML is structured as to how you achieve it. If you could edit your question to include the HTML, I can give you a more complete example.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Edited! Curious to see what you recommend!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Forgot to mention, the other portfolios are structured the exact same way, except with '.portfolio-two' or .'portfolio-three' instead of '.portfolio-one'.

Comment: @mieradi I was about to write the answer, but Andrew Cheong has already done it. His second example follows good DRY principles: https://jsfiddle.net/bfq5arcc/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Agreed. Nice and clean. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - And I was about to edit my answer to add modified HTML, when I saw your fiddle. Thanks, Rory.

Answer (score 2):

To do it literally in the fashion you wish to do it, use `.attr('class')` to get your class's name as a string, and use concatenation thereon:

```
function showContent(){
$('.portfolio-one').on('click', function(event) { 
    var className = $(this).attr('class');
    $('.' + className + '__content').animate({
    left: "5", 
    height: "100%"}, 700, "linear");
        $('.' + className + '__content').show();
        $('.' + className + '__content button').show();
        $('.' + className + '__overlay').hide();
   });
 };
```

Bravo for reaching for cleaner code, but there are even cleaner ways to go! Consider organizating your HTML such that the content, button, and overlay are descendant elements (*e.g.* children) of the element that's classed `.portfolio-xyz`. Because then, you can use descendant selectors to do your bidding:

```
function showContent(){
$('.portfolio-any').on('click', function(event) { 
    $(this).find('.portfolio-content').animate({
    left: "5", 
    height: "100%"}, 700, "linear");
        $(this).find('.portfolio-content').show();
        $(this).find('.portfolio-button').show();
        $(this).find('.portfolio-overlay').hide();
   });
 };
```

To do the above, you'd give all your portfolios a generic class like `.portfolio-any`, and same with the content, buttons, and overlays.

Comment: This is great. And a much similar method than I was trying for. Care to elaborate on how to make it even cleaner? That's all I'm striving for!

Comment: I put my statements out of order; edited. The last example I gave is the typical way to do things. Good luck!

Comment: Awesome. Much appreciated!